# performance significantly reduced when inner join table and views

Tags: sql-server

I have three views in my sql server:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[v_CompanyLabelCreate]  
AS   
SELECT   
c.Id AS Id,  
c.[Name] AS CompanyName,   
CASE WHEN r.ApprovedPatentCreativeApplication > 2 OR r.ApprovedCopyRightBookApplication + r.ApprovedCopyRightSoftwareApplication > 4 OR NumberInProduction + NumberNotInProduction > 10 THEN N'创造型'  
ELSE NULL END AS Label  
FROM Company c INNER JOIN ResearchInfo r ON c.Id = r.CompanyID  
WHERE c.Submitted = 1



CREATE VIEW [dbo].[v_CompanyLabelHighPotential]  
AS   
SELECT   
c.Id AS Id,  
c.[Name] AS CompanyName,   
CASE WHEN si1.Income >= 1000000 AND si2.Income <> 0 AND ((si1.Income -si2.Income)/si2.Income) >= 1 THEN N'潜力型'  
     WHEN n1.TotalProfit >= 500000 AND n2.TotalProfit <> 0 AND ((n1.TotalProfit - n2.TotalProfit)/n2.TotalProfit) >= 1 THEN N'潜力型'  
     WHEN nfa1.AssetsTotal >= 5000000 AND nfa2.AssetsTotal <> 0 AND ((nfa1.AssetsTotal - nfa2.AssetsTotal)/nfa2.AssetsTotal) >= 1 THEN N'潜力型'  
ELSE NULL END AS Label  
FROM Company c INNER JOIN SaleIncome si1 ON c.Id = si1.CompanyID AND si1.YearQuarterID = 2  
           INNER JOIN SaleIncome si2 ON c.Id = si2.CompanyID AND si2.YearQuarterID = 1  
           INNER JOIN NetProfit n1 ON c.Id = n1.CompanyID AND n1.YearQuarterID = 2  
  INNER JOIN NetProfit n2 ON c.Id = n2.CompanyID AND n2.YearQuarterID = 1  
  INNER JOIN NonFloatingAsset nfa1 ON c.Id = nfa1.CompanyID AND nfa1.YearQuarterID = 2  
  INNER JOIN NonFloatingAsset nfa2 ON c.Id = nfa2.CompanyID AND nfa2.YearQuarterID = 1  
WHERE c.Submitted = 1




CREATE VIEW [dbo].[v_CompanyLabelHighTotalPolicies]  
AS  
SELECT   
c.Id AS Id,   
c.[Name] AS CompanyName,   
CASE WHEN p.NumberOfPolicies >= 4 AND cp.PolicyID IS NOT NULL THEN N'政策大户'  
ELSE NULL END AS Label  
FROM Company c LEFT JOIN (SELECT CompanyID, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfPolicies FROM CompanyPolicy GROUP BY CompanyID) p ON c.Id = p.CompanyID  
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT CompanyID, PolicyID FROM CompanyPolicy WHERE PolicyID = 7) cp ON c.Id = cp.CompanyID  
WHERE c.Submitted = 1
```

When I run a select query which inner joins these three views:

```
select * 
from  v_CompanyLabelCreate clc 
  INNER JOIN v_CompanyLabelHighPotential clhp ON clc.Id = clhp.Id  
  INNER JOIN v_CompanyLabelHighTotalPolicies chtp ON clc.Id = chtp.Id
```

It is fast and smooth. However, when I try to run a select query which inner join these three views with some other tables:

```
select * 
FROM Company c 
  INNER JOIN BasicInfo b ON c.Id = b.CompanyID  
  INNER JOIN CompanyDimension cd ON c.Id = cd.CompanyID  
  INNER JOIN TotalProfit t ON c.Id = t.CompanyID AND t.YearQuarterID = 2  
  INNER JOIN SaleCost sc ON c.Id = sc.CompanyID AND sc.YearQuarterID = 2  
  INNER JOIN CompanyFinancialIndex cfi ON c.Id = cfi.CompanyID AND cfi.YearQuarterID = 6  
  INNER JOIN SaleIncome si1 ON c.Id = si1.CompanyID AND si1.YearQuarterID = 2  
  INNER JOIN SaleIncome si2 ON c.Id = si2.CompanyID AND si2.YearQuarterID = 1  
  INNER JOIN NetProfit n1 ON c.Id = n1.CompanyID AND n1.YearQuarterID = 2  
  INNER JOIN NetProfit n2 ON c.Id = n2.CompanyID AND n2.YearQuarterID = 1  
  INNER JOIN v_CompanyLabelCreate clc ON c.Id = clc.Id  
  INNER JOIN v_CompanyLabelHighPotential clhp ON clc.Id = clhp.Id  
  INNER JOIN v_CompanyLabelHighTotalPolicies chtp ON clc.Id = chtp.Id  
WHERE c.Submitted = 1
```

It looks like it will take forever to get the result (Download the execution plan here: [the execution plan](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiCFEiYvdMVygaJHeC4ut6EZMMAzNg)). Now, if I just run the query without inner joining the three views like this:

```
select * 
FROM Company c 
  INNER JOIN BasicInfo b ON c.Id = b.CompanyID  
  INNER JOIN CompanyDimension cd ON c.Id = cd.CompanyID  
  INNER JOIN TotalProfit t ON c.Id = t.CompanyID AND t.YearQuarterID = 2  
  INNER JOIN SaleCost sc ON c.Id = sc.CompanyID AND sc.YearQuarterID = 2  
  INNER JOIN CompanyFinancialIndex cfi ON c.Id = cfi.CompanyID AND cfi.YearQuarterID = 6  
  INNER JOIN SaleIncome si1 ON c.Id = si1.CompanyID AND si1.YearQuarterID = 2  
  INNER JOIN SaleIncome si2 ON c.Id = si2.CompanyID AND si2.YearQuarterID = 1  
  INNER JOIN NetProfit n1 ON c.Id = n1.CompanyID AND n1.YearQuarterID = 2  
  INNER JOIN NetProfit n2 ON c.Id = n2.CompanyID AND n2.YearQuarterID = 1  
WHERE c.Submitted = 1
```

It is fast and smooth again.

About the tables used:

1. **Company**: A table which stores company Ids and company names. Of course c.Id is the PK and it will be referred to as Company ID later.
2. **ResearchInfo**, **BasicInfo**, **CompanyDimension**, **CompanyFinancialIndex**: CompanyID is foreign key, every company only has at most one row in this table.
3. **SaleIncome, SaleCost, NetProfit, NonFloatingAsset, TotalProfit**: the combination of CompanyID and YearQuarterID work as Primary Key, although every table has an identity field which is defined as the PK.

Comment: Without table definitions and indexes this is a crap shoot. At the very least the execution plan would help massively.

Comment: You really need to post the plan. That will generally tell you where the problem is.

Comment: The execution plan is posted, please take a look at it, thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Can you post an actual execution plan instead of an estimated one?

Comment: Yeah, the ACTUAL plan is better. But even looking at the estimated plan, I see a lot of warnings about CompanyID not having statistics, and it really seems like you want a covering index on NetProfit with CompanyID, YearQuerterID) as the key, and ditto SaleIncome, SaleCost, TotalProfit, and CompanyFinancialIndex. The plan has everything going to the primary key, which isn't exactly efficient for this query.

Answer (score 0):

You also can have a missed index issue, but your query is a bit complex. You can try to reduce the complexity using cte table like (You need the field names be unique in CTEs):

```
WITH cte_tb1 
     AS (SELECT * -- UNIQUE NAMES FIELDS IS REQUIRED 
         FROM   company c 
                INNER JOIN basicinfo b 
                        ON c.id = b.companyid 
                INNER JOIN companydimension cd 
                        ON c.id = cd.companyid 
                INNER JOIN totalprofit t 
                        ON c.id = t.companyid 
                           AND t.yearquarterid = 2 
                INNER JOIN salecost sc 
                        ON c.id = sc.companyid 
                           AND sc.yearquarterid = 2 
                INNER JOIN companyfinancialindex cfi 
                        ON c.id = cfi.companyid 
                           AND cfi.yearquarterid = 6 
                INNER JOIN saleincome si1 
                        ON c.id = si1.companyid 
                           AND si1.yearquarterid = 2 
                INNER JOIN saleincome si2 
                        ON c.id = si2.companyid 
                           AND si2.yearquarterid = 1 
                INNER JOIN netprofit n1 
                        ON c.id = n1.companyid 
                           AND n1.yearquarterid = 2 
                INNER JOIN netprofit n2 
                        ON c.id = n2.companyid 
                           AND n2.yearquarterid = 1 
         WHERE  c.submitted = 1), 
     cte_tb2 
     AS (SELECT * -- UNIQUE NAMES FIELDS IS REQUIRED 
         FROM   v_companylabelcreate clc 
                INNER JOIN v_companylabelhighpotential clhp 
                        ON clc.id = clhp.id 
                INNER JOIN v_companylabelhightotalpolicies chtp 
                        ON clc.id = chtp.id) 
SELECT * 
FROM   cte_tb1 a 
       INNER JOIN cte_tb2 b 
               ON a.id = b.id
```

Comment: I tried, unfortunately it doesn't make any difference

Comment: Sorry, man. One other thing that you can try is moving your view to temporary tables. In your logic reuses the same tables a lot of times. Ever you checked the execution plan to find complex operations or missed index?